# have slivers start behind SliverAppBar

Tags: flutter

I'm looking for a way to start my slivers start behind my `SliverAppBar`. The standard way (not slivers) would be to use  `extendBody: true,` and `extendBodyBehindAppBar: true`,in the `Scaffold` widget. This doesn't work with slivers because the appbar is part of the scaffold body I suppose. Here's minimum example.. I'd like the Sliverlist to start being the appbar....

```
                      import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
  
  void main() => runApp(SilverAppBarExample());
  
  class SilverAppBarExample extends StatelessWidget {
    @override
    Widget build(BuildContext context) {
      return MaterialApp(
        home: Scaffold(
          extendBody: true,
                      extendBodyBehindAppBar: true,
          body: CustomScrollView(
            slivers: <Widget>[
              SliverAppBar(
                leading: IconButton(
                  icon: Icon(Icons.filter_1),
                  onPressed: () {
                    // Do something
                  }
                ),
                
                floating: true,
                pinned: true,
                snap: true,
                elevation: 50,
                backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
                
              ),
              new SliverList(
                  delegate: new SliverChildListDelegate(_buildList(50))
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      );
    }
  
    List _buildList(int count) {
      List<Widget> listItems = List();
  
      for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        listItems.add(new Padding(padding: new EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
            child: new Text(
                'Item ${i.toString()}',
                style: new TextStyle(fontSize: 25.0)
            )
        ));
      }
  
      return listItems;
    }
  }
```

Comment: have you managed to solve the issue? I'm stuck on this problem too

Answer (score 1):

You should use `SliverStack` widget from [sliver_tools](https://pub.dev/packages/sliver_tools) package. It works like the regular `Stack` with a difference that the widgets passed as children can be either slivers or box widgets wrapped in `SliverPositioned`.

So, the build method will become as follows:

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        body: CustomScrollView(
          slivers: <Widget>[
            SliverStack(
              children: [
                SliverList(
                    delegate: SliverChildListDelegate(_buildList(50))),
                SliverAppBar(
                  leading: IconButton(
                      icon: const Icon(Icons.filter_1),
                      onPressed: () {
                        // Do something
                      }),
                  floating: true,
                  pinned: true,
                  snap: true,
                  elevation: 50,
                  backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

Hope it helps!

Answer (score -1):

I solved it using NestedScrollView without SliverOverlapInjector
So use it as normal except remove this part

```
SliverOverlapInjector(
      handle: NestedScrollView.sliverOverlapAbsorberHandleFor(context),
),
```

and make sure your app bar is  ***pinned***, and not ***floating***

Comment: where do you put this SliverOverlapInjector

Comment: Sorry for late response ,you can set it at the top of customscrollview slivers